# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python

```
def gen_p():
    psmi = 5
    psma = 10
    ch_v = string.digits + string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
    passc = "".join(choice(ch_v) for x in range(randint(psmi, psma)))
    passe.insert(0, passc)
```

I have a problem with the python code when I want to display a response in a python entry I get:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

I'm looking for the error in my code but I can't find it.

Comment: `passe` is not defined! Is it a list? So before your for loop, you might have `passe = []`

Comment: Je ne peux pas car passe est une variable que j'ai attribué à une Entry

Comment: @Théophile please use english.

Comment: This is telling you that `passe` is set to `None`. You need to show us how you're defining `passe`.

Answer (score 1):

I building a simple project here:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
screen=Tk()
def ins(text):
    listbox.insert(0,text)
    listbox.place(x=30,y=10)
listbox=Listbox(screen)
ins("Hello")
screen.title("Simple Project")
screen.mainloop()
```

You receive this error because after place(),grid(),... then a button,label,...will become NoneType.